# Vaadin + maven problems

Tags: maven-3, vaadin7

I'm trying to setup Vaadin for a new project.
I'm following the steps documented in https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+Maven+project

The following command in empty directory:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.8
```

Gives me a following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:7.1.8) -> [Help 1]
```

I've also tried creating pom with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.1.6</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Running `mvm clean install` results in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project artifact: Could not resolve dependencies for project group:artifact:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.1.6, com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:jar:7.1.6, com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:7.1.6, com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:7.1.6: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.1.6 in http://10.255.251.14:9991/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Also there are the following warnings seen:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.1.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:jar:7.1.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:7.1.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:7.1.6 is missing, no dependency information available
```

At first we thought there might be some problems with our nexus installation, but we also tried running these commands from external machine without nexus. Same issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It successfully downloaded vaadin-client-compiler, but not the previous four mentioned in my problem. :(

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Then you have to force the update. Example: `mvn install -U`

Comment: Your answer is on the correct track, but it's not exactly what I need, because I'm interested in the releases. Have an up vote for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is related to maven repositories and not vaadin.
I've tried locating computer in other country (most likely different maven repository mirror too) and it worked.

Update: I had it working for an hour or so without changing anything and then it started failing again.
This might be related to the heartbleed bug everyone is going crazy about at the moment. Admins probably patching it all over the place and there might be some disruptions to repository services or our own network.

Comment: Ok I also thinked a similar thing... ;)

Comment: Nothing to do with "heartbleed". More than two years later, it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the list of available archetypes isn't up to date. 
Run this command `mvn archetype:update-local-catalog`